# What python library do I need to learn to scrape this website?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to download all the Sunday Crosswords from the following site.

http://epaper.timesofindia.com/Default/Client.asp?skin=pastissues2&enter=LowLevel

I can manually search for "Sunday Crossword" and get all the results I need. But the results all open in javascript pop-up windows.

http://epaper.timesofindia.com/Default/Scripting/SearchView.asp?skin=pastissues2&AppName=2&sPublication=TOIM&y=11&Content=ALL&sQuery=SUNDAY+CROSSWORD&sScope=P&x=13&ContentType=on&sSorting=IssueDateID%2Casc&sLanguage=en&Offset=1

What python library do I need to learn/use to handle issues like this?

I know the basic of urllib. Can that be used for this particular purpose?

I am a relatively new programmer and don't understand web-technologies much. So any advice on what resources to read would be helpful.

Comment: JS popups don't open on the web-site, may be it is required to authenticate?

Comment: I would be interested to see what answers you get on this one. For a simple web crawler / scraper that works with html content I have some code here: http://pastebin.com/q1NEdLJ6. However, I don't think this will work with the javascript pop-ups.

Comment: @alecxe There's no authentication required. It's the archives page of the e-paper of an Indian daily called the Times Of India. I'm assuming therefore, that I am within my rights to scrape it. But, no authentication required to access the content.

Comment: Doesn't Selenium deal with javascript? There was a question on here a little while back similar to this one about javascript web crawling.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium would be a great tool to use. Being that it drives a real browser, it can handle JavaScript popups.

Here is a link to the documentation: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html

and some video tutorials:

http://pyvideo.org/search?models=videos.video&q=selenium